# Correlation between growths variables

Tags: r, regression, correlation

I'm performing correlations between growth variables (e.g. debt growth and net income growth) and the correlation is rather strong. Nevertheless, I was wondering why when I perform the same correlation for debt growth and net income (e.g. net income 2008), so not comparing growth and growth I don't get any correlation. Finally I also tried correlation between debt and net income for my sample and didn't get any correlation neither.

Could somebody explain me why there are correlations between growths variables and not between the variables themselves? does it make sense to perform correlations between growth variables?

Comment: I can't understand your question. Can you more clearly differentiate b/t the 3 pairs of variables? It sounds like you're correlating the same pair of variables 3 times & getting different results.

Comment: It'd probably help if you displayed a sample of the data.

Comment: It's difficult to tell if this is what you're dealing with from your description, but if you are comparing correlations among raw series and differenced series (equivalently, cumulated and uncumulated), or with one raw and one differenced, then the correlations can be completely different. For example, if both raw series are increasing, they'll show a high correlation, but after differencing either, they may not show any. If one is differenced and both are cyclical, you can get a similar effect.

Answer (score 0):

(mostly copied from comments by Glen_b)  It's difficult to tell if this is what you're dealing with from your description, but if you are comparing correlations among raw series and differenced series (equivalently, cumulated and uncumulated), or with one raw and one differenced, then the correlations can be completely different.  For example, if both raw series are increasing, they'll show a high correlation, but after differencing either, they may not show any.  If one is differenced and both are cyclical, you can get a similar effect.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine one parameter is $X^2$ and the other one is $(X-2)^2$. They may have a weak correlation in the range [0,2], but their derivative ($2X$ and $2X-2$) are correlated at that range.

It shouldn't be the same for any function. Furthermore, having a big value in the correlation function doesn't mean being really connected (related). The value you give from the statistical tool you are using, is just a number which can vary due to sampling, periods, smoothing, sliding windows, ... anything else. You must study variables more precisely to be sure that they are related or not.